# What Hikari settings do

Tags: spring

I am studying about spring and db, I found this part on a spring system settings, what the this Hikari configurations really do?

I know what somethings do, but not about all.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=500
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=60000
```

Comment: Can you distinguish between those you *do* understand and those you don't (which, presumably, are the ones you are actually asking about)?

Comment: Now if only there would be some documentation on HikariCP... O wait... [there is](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#gear-configuration-knobs-baby) describing all those Hikari settings.

Comment: See definitions in https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: Yes, I can. I understood about `idle-timeout` and `minimum idle`

Answer (score 0):

I made this error yesterday.
The properties are set, when you omit `hikari.` So you have to set those instead:

```
spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=500
spring.datasource.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.validation-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.idle-timeout=60000
```

And are you sure, that you want to use a pool size of 500? That is quiet a lot.

Comment: It depends on the property, some are globally others are dependend on the underlying connection pool in use.

Comment: Ye, about 500 it's an application for study with friends at university and it's receive a lot of requisitions instantly.

Comment: According to [Hikari's documentation on the topic](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing#connections--core_count--2--effective_spindle_count), the connection pool size should depend on the **hardware** specs. The link I provided has an example about a site with up to 20k transactions per second, and the premise is that one should calculate how small the pool size should be, not how big it has to be.